# How to invoke operator from C++ in DART_API?

Tags: dart-native-extension, dart

I get error when invoke this function:

```cpp
Dart_Invoke(dh_value, Dart_NewStringFromCString("&="), 1, mask);
```

Here is error message:

```
Breaking on exception: Class 'int' has no instance method '&='.
```

How Dart programmers invoke operators in C++?

P.S.

I use Dart SDK version 1.2.0-dev.1.0

Maybe I need to switch to the stable version instead of using development version?

Comment: @mezony Sorry I didn't recognize the second line as error message as it's colored like code - changed it.

Comment: This is not C++ language. This is a print output from a program that happenes to be a C++ program. The language comments are for syntax highlightning and this error message isn't C++ syntax. I didn't recognize it as error message at first as it was colored like code. So I removed it to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is an operator of int. This is syntactic sugar for for `x = x & y`